# CSV - pulling data and writing to another CSV in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, export-to-csv

I have a large file named 'texas_boundaries.csv' which is comprised of lat/lng pairs that describe hundreds of school attendance boundaries.  It is an 800+MB file, and too large to upload to heroku.  I only need boundaries for certain schools, so I am trying to find only the rows I need and write them to a new file with this code:

```
desc "Reduce texas csv to only needed schools"
task :reduce_texas => :environment do

  require 'csv'

  file = "texas_boundaries.csv"
  headers = CSV.open(file, &:readline)
  nces_ids = School.pluck(:nces_id).uniq
  nces_ids_track = nces_ids
  file_name = 'texas_reduced_boundaries.csv'

  CSV.open(file_name, 'a') do |csv|
    csv << headers
  end

  CSV.foreach(file, :headers => true, encoding: "UTF-8") do |row|
    if nces_ids.include?(row['ncessch'])
      CSV.open(file_name, 'a') do |csv|
        csv << row
        p row['ncessch']
        nces_ids_track.delete(row['ncessch'])
      end
    end
  end

  p "Nces_ids not in reduced boundaries file: #{nces_ids_track.count}"
  p nces_ids_track

end
```

Each school has dozens of points that describe its boundary, but when I run this code, only one point is recorded in the new file.  This is demonstrated by the console output, where I expect the same nces_id to appear many times before changing to a new nces_id.

```
tomb$ rake reduce_texas
"480000801507"
"480000801508"
"480000806094"
"480000806989"
"480000811280"
"480000905246"
```

Here is a screenshot of the actual data file that shows there are many rows with nces_id = 480000801507.

[image: texas_boundaries.csv]

Only the very first row is being recorded in the new file.

[image: texas_reduced_boundaries.csv]

Any help would be very much appreciated! As a side note, this process is very slow, so if any readers see a way to speed things up please let me know.

Comment: should not be deleting `nces_ids_track.delete(row['ncessch'])`. you need to keep fetching data for multiple rows with the same id

Comment: @BlairAnderson, thanks for the comment!  I am fetching data with `nces_ids` not `nces_ids_track`, right?

Comment: the accepted answer is correct!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks suspicious:

```
nces_ids = School.pluck(:nces_id).uniq
nces_ids_track = nces_ids
```

Assignment doesn't copy `nces_ids` array, it just copies the reference. The result is that `nces_ids` and `nces_ids_track` are referencing the same array. Later you do this:

```
if nces_ids.include?(row['ncessch'])
  CSV.open(file_name, 'a') do |csv|
    #...
    nces_ids_track.delete(row['ncessch'])
  end
end
```

but `nces_ids` and `nces_ids_track` reference the same array not different arrays as expected.

Perhaps you want to say:

```
nces_ids = School.pluck(:nces_id).uniq
nces_ids_track = nces_ids.dup
# -----------------------^^^^
```

so that you have two copies of the array to work with.

Comment: yes, that code is very suspicious indeed.  Your suggestion is perfect, thank you!